# How can i get a index value of a div just clicking on it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change the class of an specific div that i click, using this:

```js
let divs = document.querySelectorAll('.x');

function idk(){
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(divs, function(element) {
    element.classList.add('y');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(divs, function(element) {
      element.classList.remove('x');  
    });
  });
}
```

```css
.y{
   transition: 0.5s;
   transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="d1">
   <div id="c1" class="x" onclick="idk()">a</div>
   <div id="c2" class="x" onclick="idk()">b</div>
   <div id="c3" class="x" onclick="idk()">c</div>
</div>
```

This code above works well, but only in all `div`s at the same time, not with only that I've clicked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for `id`s and [you should not use inline event attributes like `onclick`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991) and instead separate your JavaScript from your HTML and use the standard [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead.

Also, no need for `Array.prototype.forEach()` as `.forEach` is supported on the node list returned from `querySelectorAll()`.

To get the index, just use the index parameter that `.forEach()` exposes:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".x").forEach(function(element, index){
  element.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    console.log(index);
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="x">a</div>
<div class="x">b</div>
<div class="x">c</div>
```

But, in order to change the class of the clicked element, you can just access the clicked element directly from within the event handler with the `this` keyword:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".x").forEach(function(element, index){
  element.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    // Within a DOM element event handling function, the keyword
    // "this" will reference the element that triggered the event.
    this.classList.remove("x");
    this.classList.add("y");
  });
});
```

```css
.x { color: blue; }
.y { 
  color: red; 
  transition: 1.5s;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="x">a</div>
<div class="x">b</div>
<div class="x">c</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Don't use `onclick` inline attributes, JS should be in one place only and that's the respective tag or file. Use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead
- Use [classList.toggle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) to toggle your `"y"` className

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.x');

const divClickHandler = (evt) =>  {
  const elThis = evt.currentTarget;  
  divs.forEach((el) => el.classList.toggle("y", el === elThis ));
  console.log(elThis.id); // You don't need this
};

divs.forEach((el) => el.addEventListener("click", divClickHandler));
```

```css
.x { background: gray; }
.y { background: gold; }
```

```html
<div id="d1">
  <div id="c1" class="x">1</div>
  <div id="c2" class="x">2</div>
  <div id="c3" class="x">3</div>
</div>
```

as you can see from the example above, you *can* extract the ID, but you don't necessarily need it.

Answer (score -1):

You could pass in the div ID to the test function like

`<div id="c3" class="x" onclick="idk('c3')"></div>`

then your test function could look like:

```
function test(id){
  let foundDiv = document.getElementById(d)
  foundDiv.classList.add('y');
  foundDiv.classList.remove('x');
}
```